# How to generate nlog for specific log size

Tags: xml, iis, app-config, nlog

I am trying to generate the nlog for specific log size but dont get a way around to do this can some one please help. I am using the following nlog also i would like to change the location of current log file to a new log file location

```
<targets>
  <target name="f1" xsi:type="File" fileName="test.log.txt" layout="${threadname} ${longdate}   
${callsite} ${logger}[${level}] ${message}" />
  <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${threadname} ${longdate} ${callsite}   
${logger}[${level}] ${message}" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <!--<logger name="Quartz.*" level="Warn" />-->
  <logger name="*" writeTo="f1" minlevel="Info" />
  <logger name="*" writeTo="console" minlevel="Debug" />
</rules>
  </nlog>
  <common>
<logging>
  <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
    <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
  </factoryAdapter>
</logging>
```

Comment: for example generate a  log file for every 1gb and puts a date infront of it, and a new log file for another 1gb and so forth

Comment: can any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File%20Target#size-based-file-archival) example will help you. It's not 100% what you need but it is a start. It will archive a log file when it reaches specified file size but it does not put date in front of it. You could set the file name to include a date of creation. I don't know if it is possible to set the filename after it reached specified size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `archiveDateFormat`, arhci and `archiveFileNmae` attributes

```
<target xsi:type="File" 
        name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/test.log.txt" 
        archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMddHHmmss" 
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/{#}.test.log.txt" 
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"  archiveAboveSize="100240" />
```